# How do I capture variables outside the scope of a closure in Rust?

Tags: closures, rust

I'm writing a case-insensitive anagram finder given a word and a list of words. I have the following code:

```
pub fn anagrams_for(s: &'static str, v: &[&'static str]) -> Vec<&'static str> {
    let mut s_sorted: Vec<_> = s.to_lowercase().chars().collect();
    s_sorted.sort();

    v.iter().filter_map(move |word: &str| {
        let mut word_sorted: Vec<_> = word.to_lowercase().chars().collect();
        word_sorted.sort();

        if word_sorted == s_sorted && s.to_lowercase() != word.to_lowercase() {
            Some(word)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }).collect()
}
```

The logic of this is to sort the lowercase given word, and for each word in the vector, do the same. If the words are different pre-sort (to eliminate self-anagrams) but are the same post-sort, add it to the output.

The above seems to have problems capturing `s` and `s_sorted` from the surrounding scope, though, because when I compile I get the following error:

> error: type mismatch: the type `[closure@src/lib.rs:23:25: 32:6 s_sorted:_, s:_]` implements the trait `for<'r> core::ops::FnMut<(&'r str,)>`, but the trait `core::ops::FnMut<(&&str,)>` is required (expected &-ptr, found str)

When I looked at the description of this error type ([E0281]), I found the following TL;DR:

> The issue in this case is that `foo` is defined as accepting a `Fn` with no
>   arguments, but the closure we attempted to pass to it requires one argument.

This is confusing because I thought [move closures capture variables](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html#move-closures) from the surrounding scope.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with capturing variables in the closure. Let's check out the error message again, reformatted a bit:

```
type mismatch:
    the type `[closure@<anon>:5:25: 14:6 s_sorted:_, s:_]`
    implements the trait `for<'r> core::ops::FnMut<(&'r str,)>`,
    but the trait `core::ops::FnMut<(&&str,)>` is required
    (expected &-ptr, found str)
```

And more clearly:

```
found:    for<'r> core::ops::FnMut<(&'r str,)>
expected:         core::ops::FnMut<(&&str,)>
```

And zooming in even further:

```
found:    &'r str
expected: &&str
```

The culprit is this: `|word: &str|`.

You have declared that your closure accepts a string slice, but **that's not what the iterator yields**. `v` is a slice of `&str`, and an iterator over a slice returns references to the items in the slice. Each iterator element is a `&&str`.

Change your closure to `|&word|` and it will work. This uses pattern matching to dereference the closure argument once before the value is bound to `word`. Equivalently (but less idiomatically), you could use `|word|` and then `*word` inside the closure.

---

Additionally...

1. You don't need to restrict yourself to `'static` strings:

   ```
   pub fn anagrams_for<'a>(s: &str, v: &[&'a str]) -> Vec<&'a str> {
   ```
2. It doesn't need to be a `move` closure.
3. Extract the logic of creating the vector of sorted chars. This helps ensure that the logic stays consistent between the two *and* means you don't have to declare those vectors as mutable for longer than needed.

```
fn sorted_chars(s: &str) -> Vec<char> { 
    let mut s_sorted: Vec<_> = s.to_lowercase().chars().collect();
    s_sorted.sort();
    s_sorted
}

pub fn anagrams_for<'a>(s: &str, v: &[&'a str]) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let s_sorted = sorted_chars(s);

    v.iter().filter_map(|&word| {
        let word_sorted = sorted_chars(word);

        if word_sorted == s_sorted && s.to_lowercase() != word.to_lowercase() {
            Some(word)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }).collect()
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: I suspect that by taking a reference to `word`, this would be much faster than cloning the iterator. Do you think it's better to continue to use a move closure or to use the other answer (which changes the type of the closure parameter and clones the iterator)?

Comment: @erip *than cloning the iterator* — it's not the entire iterator that is cloned; it's just an additional adapter that clones each element as it is yielded. My hope and gut feeling is that the two solutions would be equally performant. **I** believe that this solution would be more idiomatic in this case. Note that you don't need a `move` closure anyway (I've updated).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Very helpful and comprehensive.

Comment: I also think this is more idiomatic. Remove the type annotations wherever possible... (IMO :3)

Comment: Regarding the last note: you can also move the additional `sorted_chars` function definition into the other function. Avoids global namespace clutter.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that you are attempting to create a `Vec<&'static str>` from a sequence of `&&'static str`.

```
pub fn anagrams_for(s: &'static str, v: &[&'static str]) -> Vec<&'static str> {
    let mut s_sorted: Vec<_> = s.to_lowercase().chars().collect();
    s_sorted.sort();

    v.iter().cloned().filter_map(|word: &'static str| {
        let mut word_sorted: Vec<_> = word.to_lowercase().chars().collect();
        word_sorted.sort();

        if word_sorted == s_sorted && s.to_lowercase() != word.to_lowercase() {
            Some(word)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }).collect()
}
```

The `cloned` call is necessary to go from a `&&'static str` to a `&'static str`. This is an inexpensive operation since a `&str` is just a pointer to some utf8 sequence, plus a length.

Edit: actually an even better solution is to clone as late as possible

```
v.iter().filter_map(move |word: &&'static str| { // <--- adapted the type to what is actually received
    let mut word_sorted: Vec<_> = word.to_lowercase().chars().collect();
    word_sorted.sort();

    if word_sorted == s_sorted && s.to_lowercase() != word.to_lowercase() {
        Some(word.clone()) // <--- moved clone operation here
    } else {
        None
    }
}).collect()
```

Comment: Well that was pretty silly. Would you mind adding why the `cloned` call is needed as an edit?